# How to test sharing social media link preview on local environment?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to set social media share options with preview, but it doesn't work for me on my local environment. The meta tags are present in the link that i'm sharing but because the site is in development stage the social media platforms can't reach it, and the preview doesn't show.

Is there a way to test the preview before deployment to production?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, tools like https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator require a public URL *somewhere*. Why not generate the HTML and host it statically, for testing purposes?

Comment: We don't want to change the production version, and our staging version requires authorization and has the same problem as the local version. we don't want to deploy another version just for that if possible.

Comment: You don't have to *"deploy another version"*, just one HTML page somewhere to test the basic template.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a google chrome extension to test your page previews from a local environment.

It is called Social Share Preview

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/social-share-preview/ggnikicjfklimmffbkhknndafpdlabib/related?hl=en

Comment: this extension doesn't render preview properly. once i deployed and test in facebook sharing debugger, it's different

Comment: I would imagine the preview would look different in the context of where it is being rendered. I dont think the tool is meant to give you an exact 100% preview. If you share a link in twitter they could display that preview differently than facebook would or some other social media platform. They will choose how it looks..